# mysql query select parent-child recursive

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I do not know how to select query recursive..

I have table like this:

```
idmenu   idparent     Title
  1         0         menu_parent1
  2         1         menu_child2
  3         1         menu_child3
  4         0         menu_parent4
  5         4         menu_child5
  6         4         menu_child6
```

how do the results like this

```
  idmenu    idparent          Title
  1       menu_parent1     menu_parent1
  2       menu_parent1     menu_child2
  3       menu_parent1     menu_child3
  4       menu_parent4     menu_parent4
  5       menu_parent4     menu_child5
  6       menu_parent4     menu_child6
```

anyone help me..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zero doesnt refer to something, can you fix it? the answer may be like this

```
SELECT aa.idmenu,
       bb.title AS idparent,
       aa.title 
FROM [yourtablename] aa
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [yourtablename] bb 
                  ON aa.idmenu=bb.idmenu
```

Comment: Its 0 to determine the child's parents..
and it only exists in one table..sorry my english is bad